# How do I set the css color of a bootstrap switch?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I change the blue to another color in this bootstrap switch?
I tried changing the color and background-color of the input element but it didn't change the switch color.

[image]

Here is the html and the bootstrap [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/forms/#switches)

```html
<div class="custom-control custom-switch ">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch1" (click)="changeState($event)">
  <label class="custom-control-label text-yb" for="customSwitch1">Activate</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to avoid using `!important` to reset color and bg-color, you may use `filter:hue-rotate(xxdeg) ;` via a custom class

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/hue-rotate()
>
> The `hue-rotate()` CSS function rotates the hue of an element and its contents. Its result is a `<filter-function>`.

See also :  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hue

```css
.hr45::before {
  filter: hue-rotate(45deg)
}

.hr90::before {
  filter: hue-rotate(90deg)
}

.hr180::before {
  filter: hue-rotate(180deg)
}

.hr225::before {
  filter: hue-rotate(225deg)
}

.hr327brgtns108::before {
  filter: hue-rotate(327deg) brightness(108%);
}

html {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  margin: auto;
}

label {
  color: #6BBECC;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body class="m-auto">
  <div class="custom-control custom-switch ">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch0" (click)="changeState($event)">
    <label class="custom-control-label text-yb hr327brgtns108" for="customSwitch0">Activate #17a2b8</label>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-control custom-switch ">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch1" (click)="changeState($event)">
    <label class="custom-control-label text-yb hr45" for="customSwitch1">Activate lightpurple</label>
  </div>

  <div class="custom-control custom-switch ">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch2" (click)="changeState($event)">
    <label class="custom-control-label text-yb hr90" for="customSwitch2">Activate pinkish </label>
  </div>

  <div class="custom-control custom-switch ">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch3" (click)="changeState($event)">
    <label class="custom-control-label text-yb hr180" for="customSwitch3">Activate brownish </label>
  </div>

  <div class="custom-control custom-switch ">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input hr180" id="customSwitch4" (click)="changeState($event)">
    <label class="custom-control-label text-yb hr225" for="customSwitch4">Activate greenish</label>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks. I tried looking up the hue of #17a2b8 and I see 188.2deg, but after I applied it to the hue-rotate function it doesn't show up as correct color after rendering. What is the correct deg for #17a2b8?

Comment: @user1186050 you will need to reset brightness() too: try : `filter: hue-rotate(327deg) brightness(108%);`

Comment: thanks! is there a website that I can visit to find these calculated values?

Comment: the wiki shows you a ruler that let you find  out the degres you can set an average  hue-rotate  0-360deg your blue was at average 230 and your color at average 200 , so 360 - 30 is average 330 that's where i started from   . The way i did was to put the the custom input hover a background of the color you try to get. At a point , it will be fine, too dark or too bright. you can finish the tunning with contrast() and or brightness() . for the math you look for, it would be easier to start from an rgb() color but i did not go to school long enough to help efficiently here :)

Comment: any color you want to rotate will be set at 0/360 . the rulers starts with a red and the blue is at 240

Comment: Quick question - how can I change the color without changing the color of the label. This solution changes the label color as well as the switch color.

Comment: if you use the ::before selector it should not , text label in the example above do not ;)

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this to your css file, or add it to your html file between `<style>` ... `</style>`, to change the background color of the switch - it also removes or modifies the blue circle and shadow. =]

```
.form-switch .form-check-input {
    height: 24px;
    width: 48px;
}
.form-switch .form-check-input:focus {
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='-4 -4 8 8'%3e%3ccircle r='3' fill='rgba(0,0,0,0.25)'/></svg>");
}
.form-switch .form-check-input:checked {
    background-color: #30D158;
    border-color: #30D158;
    border: none;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='-4 -4 8 8'%3e%3ccircle r='3' fill='rgba(255,255,255,1.0)'/></svg>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply apply your own style like this :

```
.custom-control-input:checked~.custom-control-label::before {
    color: #fff;
    border-color: #38b44a !important;
    background: #38b44a !important;
}
```