# How to change bootstrap switch color without changing the label color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I posted this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65347357/how-do-i-set-the-css-color-of-a-bootstrap-switch#65347409) to change the color of the bootstrap switch, but it changes the label color as well.

QUESTION - Is there a way to change the switch without the label being changed?
I want my label to be  #17a2b8 and if I add this as the color it gets mixed with the color of the filter

Here is my original code with answer

```css
.hr327brgtns108 {
  filter: hue-rotate(327deg) brightness(108%);
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-control custom-switch ">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch0" (click)="changeState($event)">
  <label class="custom-control-label text-yb hr327brgtns108" for="customSwitch0">Activate #17a2b8</label>
</div>
```

Comment: The answer in the original question works by adding a pseudo before element to the label so there's quite a bit more to it than the snippet you have posted here which does not do anything color-wise. It may be helpful to post the full code so we can see it change the label color. When I run the answer from your original question it does not change the label color, the labels remain black.

Comment: *if you use the ::before selector it should not , text label in the example above do not* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65347357/how-do-i-set-the-css-color-of-a-bootstrap-switch/65347409?noredirect=1#comment115538481_65347409 don't copy/paste a code before you understand how it works ;)